# Data Collection from Jquery

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

How i can get the data selected data from jquery and pass it to the other page,page2.php to page3.php.I just want to save it in a variable and post it,from page3.php i will grab the data.

```
function refreshPrices() {

   var beg=<?php echo isset($beg) ? $beg : 0 ?>;
   var inte=<?php echo isset($int) ? $int : 0 ?>;
   var advn=<?php echo isset($adv) ? $adv : 0 ?>;
   var currentTotalValue = 0;
    currentTotalValue = currentTotalValue + beg + inte + advn;
    $("#results div").each(function() {
        if (!isNaN(parseInt($(this).find("span").text().substring(1)))) {
            currentTotalValue += parseInt($(this).find("span").text().substring(1));
        }
    });


    $("#totalValue").text("$" + currentTotalValue)
}

$(document).ready(function() {

    $('#1').click(function() {
        //var row = $(this);
        if (($(this).attr('checked')) == 'checked') {
            $('#result').append("-PDF Document <html><span style=float:right>$100</span></html>");
        }
        else {
            $('#result').text("");
        }

        refreshPrices()


    });

    $('#2').click(function() {
        if (($(this).attr('checked')) == 'checked') {
            $('#result2').append("-Video <html><span style=float:right>$200</span></html> ");
        }
        else {
            $('#result2').text("");
        }

        refreshPrices()
    });
});
```

Comment: sessionStorage is necessary???

Comment: [window.location.search](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.location)

Comment: example.com/page3.php?result=??how to grab the selected values

Comment: See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/901115/how-can-i-get-query-string-values)

Answer (score 1):

```
window.location("page3.php?q="+data);
```

Where data is the data that needs to be passed to the other page

Comment: can you pls tell how to grab the checked(checkboxex) data from the above code,just give me one example